# Simple Java Fish in a Pond multiplying a number of fish in a pond

Tags: string, loops, nested-loops

I'm trying to increment the number of fish in a pond to 43.

I'm not worried about the "tank" but more about multiplying the fish by 43.

I have a nested loop, which gives me 100 fish, but I'm not sure on how to get the exact number of fish I need?

```
 for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
 { 

 for (int j=0; j<10; j++)
 { 

    System.out.print(" <#><");

 }


----------------------------------------------------
| <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< |
| <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< |
| <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< |
| <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< |
| <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< |
| <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< |
| <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< |
| <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< |
| <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< |
| <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< <#>< |
----------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if( (i*10+j) < 43) {
   System.out.print(" <#><");
}
else{
System.out.print("     ");
}
```

Comment: Great, now I just need it to stop printing after every 10 (out of 43) fish and start a new line with the next set of fish. The code I have at the moment results in one line of 43 fish

Comment: public class aFish
{



    public aFish()
    {for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
       { 
           for (int j=0; j<10; j++)
           { 

           if( (i*10+j) < 43) {
           System.out.print(" <#><"); 
           }
           else{
           System.out.print("     ");
          }

    
        }
}
}
}